# Tailwindcss purges whitelisted tag

Tags: tailwind-css

I would like to preserve a line like:

```
h3 {
        @apply text-2xl mt-8 mb-4;
   }
```

Unfortunately, tailwind is purging the h3-tag :-/

This is the config:

```
purge: {
        content: ['./resources/js/**/*.vue',],
        options: {
            whitelist: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'],
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

purge.options.whitelist is an array of class names you want to whitelist. So what your code whitelisting is .h1,.h2 & .h3 classes not actual tags.

Solution

```
/* purgecss start ignore */

h3 {
     @apply text-2xl mt-8 mb-4;
   }

/* purgecss end ignore */
```